# Passing a nested list of objects with objects in post ajax method for web api

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi, inner-classes, asp.net-core-7.0

I am stuck in situation where I have nested list of objects inside objects. I am stuck and can't move any further.

Working fine without passing oNestedClass.

And I'm having trouble passing a list of objects via JSON to Web Api.

The controller method:

```
[HttpPost("SaveDocuments")]
public IActionResult SaveDocuments(Documenttest saveDocs)
{
    var docTypeList = docContext.SaveDocuments(saveDocs);
    return Ok(docTypeList);
}
```

Class:

```
public class Documenttest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? Gender { get; set; }
    public List<NestedClass>? oNestedClass { get; set; } = new();
}

public class NestedClass
{
    public string? StdType { get; set; }
    public IFormFile? StdFile { get; set; }
}
```

Calling from .aspx page:

```
$("#postform").submit(function (e) {
var apiurl = "https://localhost:7168/api/NestClass/SaveDocuments?";
var fileUpload = $(".uplFile");

var stdDetails = [];

for (var i = 0; i < fileUpload.length; i++) {
    var files = fileUpload[i];
    
    if (files.files.length > 0) {
        debugger
        stdDetails.push({ "StdType ": i, "StdFile ": files.files[i] });
    }
}

var data = {
    "FirstName": $("#txtFirstName").val(),
    "LastName": $("#txtLastName").val(),
    "Gender": $("#txtGender").val(),
    "oNestedClass": JSON.stringify(stdDetails)
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: apiurl,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (d) {
        alert("Saved Successfully");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error please try again");
    }
});

e.preventDefault();});
```

Comment: Could you share more html code about your "Calling from .aspx page" ? Besides, what's your ExternalDocuments model ? From your code, you have AddExternalDocuments post action in api? But your url is "https://localhost:7168/api/NestClass/TestNestedClass?";  , what is TestNestedClass?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `formdata` to pass the file. Note we pass the data binded by name attribute, such us: `saveDocs.oNestedClass[" + i + "].StdFile` , to keep same as the api action parameter **saveDocs**.

I have a work demo like below, you can refer to it:

1.change your  code like :

```
$("#postform").submit(function (e) {
        var apiurl = "https://localhost:7019/api/NestClass/SaveDocuments";
        var fileUpload = $(".uplFile");        
        var formData = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < fileUpload.length; i++) {
            var files = fileUpload[i];          
            if (files.files.length > 0) {
                debugger
                formData.append("saveDocs.oNestedClass[" + i + "].StdFile", files.files[i]);
                formData.append("saveDocs.oNestedClass[" + i + "].StdType", i);                                                         
            }         
        }
        formData.append("saveDocs.FirstName", $("#txtFirstName").val());
        formData.append("saveDocs.LastName", $("#txtLastName").val());
        formData.append("saveDocs.Gender", $("#txtGender").val());
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: apiurl,         
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (d) {
                alert("Saved Successfully");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error please try again");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();      
    });
```

2.add `[FromForm]` to recieve formdata

```
[HttpPost("SaveDocuments")]
public IActionResult SaveDocuments([FromForm]Documenttest saveDocs)
{
    var docTypeList = docContext.SaveDocuments(saveDocs);
    return Ok(docTypeList);
}
```

result:

[image]